Вывод в консоль шахматных символов (юникод)
имеется массив шахматной доски,
char board[8][8]
    {
        //0 - пустая клетка, 1- черная пешка, 2- черный конь.... 7 - белая пешка, 8 - белый конь...
        {4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
        {10, 8, 9, 11, 12, 9, 8, 10}
    };

массив символов фигур
const wchar_t figures[13] {L'▮', L'♟', L'♞', L'♝', L'♜', L'♛', L'♚', L'♙', L'♘', L'♗', L'♖', L'♕', L'♔'};

метод конвертации числа в соответствующую фигуру
 wchar_t convert(char figure){
        return figures[figure];
    };

и метод вывода всей доски
void render() {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                wcout<<board[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

не хочет ничего выводить, при этом когда в mainе писал cout<<"♞";  фигура коня выводилась без проблем (консоль vscode)

Сделайте board тоже типом wchar_t

Вы не вызываете convert при выводе

сделал board wchar_t, не помогло. convert забыл в самом вопросе написать, что с ним что без него не работает.

пока что единственное решение которое я смог найти - непосредственно в методе render выводить символы фигурок, то есть for(...{for(...{switch(board[i][j]){case 1: cout<<"♟"; break;.....}}}
сколькими вариантами не пробовал, сохранить символ шахматной фигуры в какой-нибудь переменной (неважно какого типа, char, wchar_t, chart16_t, char32_t) и вывести ее в таком же виде не получается, выводит что угодно кроме фигурки.

Стандартная консоль Windows не поддерживает символы Unicode. Для этого нужно указать кодовую страницу (англ. code-page), в которой эти символы есть.
